# How to convert batchdataset into numpy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to convert batchdataset into numpy array with images names and labels (0 and 1). Here is my code:

```
data = image_dataset_from_directory('male-female', labels='inferred')
```

The output is: `Found 3330 files belonging to 2 classes.`

But how to make it into numpy with images and label?

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @M.Innat I want to use numpy array into train_test_split. But i need it to numpy first

Comment: Then why use the generator at the first place?

Comment: @M.Innat I use the generator because there is a two folder "men" and "women", but i can't see it inside data because it just show <BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 256, 256, 3), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)> when i print it

Comment: Can you look at this link for answer. https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=zh-cn#as_numpy_iterator